# unable to connect between SQL Developer and Oracle VM Virtualbox

Tags: listener

I have setup an Oracle DB within Oracle VirtualBox and I am trying to connect to it using SQL Developer installed on the same desktop. It worked initially but has since stopped connecting. It seems like there is an issue with my listener I have been unable to figure out. My listener is showing no services supported now when I pull status.

```
'''# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT = 1539))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

~                                                                                                                                 
~                                                                                                                                 
~                                                                                                                                 
~'''       

'''[oracle@ol7-122 admin]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-FEB-2021 12:57:58

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT=1539)))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00505: Operation timed out

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                08-FEB-2021 10:14:20
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 44 min. 37 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ol7-122/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT=1539)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully'''
```

Comment: Is the database up? Can you ping ol7-122.localdomain from your Linux VM? Did you disable the firewall on the Linux VM?

Comment: I have started the database up and I have disabled the firewall.

Comment: I am able to ping ol7-122.localdomain from within the VM.

Comment: what do you see now when you do lsnrctl status?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett lsnrctl status is posted in the code block above

Comment: I'm not sure. What happens if you do lsnrctl start?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started

Comment: try stopping and starting it again - lsnrctl stop lsnrctl start - once you disable the firewall it may start without the TNS-12535 error. If it is throwing an error starting then something is keeping it from listening on port 1539 on your host. All it is doing is listening on that host and port so either that host is not working or the port.

Comment: so i get,
`Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT=1539)))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00505: Operation timed out`
but it later says successfully completed but listener supports no services

Comment: Most likely cause is firewall. Make sure it is really off and reboot your VM.

Comment: You might see if something else is using that port. Something like this might help netstat -an | grep 1539 Oracle uses port 1521 normally. Something else could be using 1539.

Comment: [oracle@ol7-122 admin]$ netstat -an | grep 1539
tcp6       0      0 :::1539                 :::*                    LISTEN     
[oracle@ol7-122 admin]$

Comment: Ok. Something is listening on 1539. Is either your Oracle listener or something else. Why don't you change the port in your listener.ora to 1521 which is the standard Oracle port and see if that works? You could do netstat -an | grep 1521 to make sure nothing else is listening on port 1521 before you change the port to 1521 in your listener.ora.